# How to replace all characters of a String with another character in Swift?

Tags: swift

I wanted to know how I could replace all the characters of a `String` with another character. For example, I would want to replace a `String` of `"Apples"` to `"??????"`, which as you can see is dependent on the character count of the original `String`. Is there anyway to signify a character? I tried using the `replacingOccurrences(of: width:)` method, but I couldn't figure out how to signify a character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to replace the entire string, "Apples", with "??????" — [`init(repeating:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427723-init) should work fine.

```
let string = "Apples"
let obscured = String(repeating: "?", count: string.count)
print(obscured)
```

Result:

```
??????
```

Comment: This is very good answer, we could use this function in building Array as well like this code `let array: [String] = Array(repeating: "Hello", count: 10); print(array)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replacingOccurrences` as the following:

```
let testString = "This is an Apples"
let world= "Apples"
let rep=""
let c=0
while(c < world.count) {
    rep=rep+"?"
    c+=1
}

var testStringReplacedOccurences = testString.replacingOccurrences(of: world,
                                                                   with: rep)

print("testStringReplacedOccurences:", testStringReplacedOccurences)
```

Result:

```
This is an ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

String is a Collection, so you can use function "map"

```
let string = "Apple"
let newString = String(string.map { _ in "?" })
```